# my.cnf in server directory, why

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, database, shell

On my **Ubuntu** machine, I have installed **MySQL** .

I notice that there are `/etc/my.cnf` file which contain the content (only two lines):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
max_allowed_packet = 512M
```

While there is also `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with a long content like:

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
...
...
```

For me, it looks like both are configurations for MySQL server, but Why there are two `my.cnf` in different locations, can't the content to be merged to one my.cnf ? What is the purpose to have seperate `my.cnf` for MySQL server ?

Comment: And you (or someone else) has not created that `/etc/my.cnf` by hand? Perhaps some program added that? By default it should not be there, unless Ubuntu folk has done something weird; in Debian that file is not present.

Comment: Agreed, there should only be 1 my.cnf. there is only 1 that is being used anyway.

Comment: This is my personal working machine, only me touch this machine, and I have never created /etc/my.cnf , until today I notice it is there...

Comment: `ls -l /etc/my.cnf` to see the modification time? Are you sure it is created after installing MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu MySQL packages create the configuration file in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, so if you have a `/etc/my.cnf` file, it is because either a package (probably from multiverse) or a tool you've used, created it.

If you're unsure where the file came from, you can see if it came from a package by using `dpkg --search file.name` , example output below

```
root@lamp01:~# dpkg --search my.cnf
mysql-common: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Ultimately, neither of those config options are particularly dangerous, so you'd be safe to merge them into `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and restart MySQL. Though you want to keep an eye on `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G` because if your MySQL service gets busy and you don't have a lot of RAM, your system could get low on memory.

If you're looking to fine tune MySQL, I suggest downloading and running https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl

You'll want to make sure that you let your MySQL service run under normal load for 24-48 hours before running `mysqltuner` though, as it works best when it can analyze MySQL's various performance characteristics under normal/usual load.